# Gatling - How to set up Looping users?

Tags: gatling

According to [the documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup) apparently I can either insert a fixed number of users at a per-second rate for a given time using `constantUsersPerSec(rate) during(duration)` or insert a number of users using `atOnceUsers(nbUsers)`.

What I would like is a fixed number of concurrent users looping. You using `constantUsersPerSec(5)`, if the first batch didn't finish, in the next sec, five new users will be pushed. I would like to only push a new user when the any finishes.

In another words I want something like: `atOnceUsers(nbUsers)` and whenever any ends up, add another one and keep that up for 5 minutes

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [`constantConcurrentUsers`](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup#closed-model)?

Answer (score 2):

> What I would like is a fixed number of concurrent users

atOnceUsers

> looping

https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario#loop-statements

Injection profile only control users spawning. Users' lifespan is controlled by the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want

```
constantConcurrentUsers(5) during (5 minutes)
```

Comment: This is the best way, after every user finishes your cycle, another one will start another cycle

Comment: It does something very different from what's requested = "I would like is a fixed number of concurrent users looping". With "constantConcurrentUsers", you'll be creating new connections, new cookies, etc.